# Obtain specific cell-value based on another cell-value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell, vlookup

Hope you're well.

I am currently working on trying to obtain the value of a specific cell based on another cell's value.

If you take the example below:

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IErZz.jpg)

What I'm trying to achieve is rather simple. On C1, I need to add a formula that obtain the latest value in column C, however the value that needs to be used must have a 'Yes' value assigned to it, on column D. In the example above, you can clearly see what I want to achieve but I have hard-coded the number 72 in it. The formula, ideally, would obtain this value automatically, as 72 (in cell C5) has a 'Yes' on column D (D5).

I'm not so sure on how to build this formula.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Will it always be all "Yes" above the last "Yes", or can there be "No" mixed in? How many rows will this be?

Answer (score 0):

In `C1` put the formula `=LOOKUP("Yes", D4:D1000, C4:C1000)`.

This will find the last occurrence of "Yes" and return the value in the adjacent `C` cell to `C1`.

Would you rather have a dynamic range? Or have it based on your dates? The above formula would only be useful so long as you sort your table by date, oldest to newest top to bottom respectively.

For dynamic ranges, we can simplify things by working with Named Ranges. Name your respective columns as such:

Date `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)`

Reconcile `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D),1)`

[image]

We can then use these named ranges, in combination with the formula grab74 provided to find the most recent value of an item marked "Yes" under reconcile.

In cell `C1` enter `=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDEX(Date*(Reconcile="Yes"),,)),Date:Reconcile,3,FALSE)`

Now regardless of how many entries you have past row 4, cell `C1` will always show you the value of the most recent reconciled item.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use Named Ranges, and you just want a really long forumla you can put in `C1` the following:

`=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDEX(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)*(OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D),1)="Yes"),,)),OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1):OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$4,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$D),1),3,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(INDEX(A4:A1000*(D4:D1000="Yes"),,)),A4:D1000,3,FALSE)
```

The inner part checks if `column D` has value "Yes". In that case cells in `column A` are multiplied by 1 (`TRUE`), otherwise by 0 (`FALSE`).
After that it gets the maximum value of the date, that is the latest and it returns the corresponding amount.

If you have a lot of data, however, it could be slow.